# Calculate Password Possibilities With Specific Character Pattern

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

So i need to estimate the number of possibilities of a 8 characters password all stick together with a specified pattern wish have only:

uppercase letter and numbers. no special characters

The pattern is :  Number, Number, Up Letter, Up Letter, Number, Up Letter, Number, Up Letter

I try to understand Combination formula and Probability and combinatorics but i didn't find the solution yet.

I admire the guys or girls who will find the solution because my brain plasticity is probably far less than those who will find it.

Comment: What would it be for a three-character password with a number between two upper-case letters? A0A, A0B, ..., Z9Z

Answer (score 1):

There are 10 numbers from 0 to 9 and 26 different (uppercase) letters in the english alphabet. Making a password one will first choose from 10 different numbers and for each of these one can choose from 10 different numbers and so on. The total number of possibilities is:

$10 * 10 * 26 * 26 * 10 * 26 * 10 * 26 = 10^4\cdot 26^4$

Comment: Did you mean $10^4 \cdot 26^4$?  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Use **\times** to generate $\times$ if you want :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)